# Accessing a lower order subnet

Tags: networking

The configuration: Internet -> subnet 1 (S1) -> subnet 2 (S2) (my router) -> My PC

I know that S1 cannot access S2 as the open internet cannot access S1, but as S1 can access the internet is it possible for S2 to access IP's from S1?

Comment: I'm having a real hard time understanding the question, and I understand subnetting and how network hardware handles traffic.  Even the provided answer to your question, by Daniel B, starts off saying "I assume you"...  I suggest trying to rephrase question to be a bit more clear.  Go ahead and use the example subnets (addresses starting with 192.0.2 or 198.51.100. or 203.0.113, per RFC 5735) or private IPs (addresses starting with 10 or 172.16 through 172.31 or 192.168) if that will help, and mention where there appear to be routers (create a diagram), and that ought to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you’re referring to a double NAT scenario, where the routers between the Internet and S1 and between S1 and S2 are both doing NAT.

In this case, **yes**, hosts from S2 can access all hosts from S1. The WAN interface of the S2-router will appears as a regular host on S1. All requests will appear to come from this router.